# Best way to "zip" together two datasets with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two data structures that look like this:

```
const labels = [
  "2020-07-30",
  "2020-07-31",
  "2020-08-01",
  "2020-08-02",
  "2020-08-03",
  "2020-08-04",
  "2020-08-05",
  "2020-08-06"
]

const data = {
  "datasetOne": [
    {
      "date": "2020-07-30",
      "metric": "someMetric",
      "value": 5.6,
      "dataset": "datasetOne"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-07-31",
      "metric": "someMetric",
      "value": 5.9,
      "dataset": "datasetOne"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-08-01",
      "metric": "someMetric",
      "value": 5.7,
      "dataset": "datasetOne"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-08-02",
      "metric": "someMetric",
      "value": 7.7,
      "dataset": "datasetOne"
    }
  ],
  "datasetTwo": [
    {
      "date": "2020-08-02",
      "metric": "someOtherMetric",
      "value": 7.7,
      "dataset": "datasetTwo"
    }
  ]
};
```

I need to fill the records in each dataset e.g. `data.datasetOne, data.DatasetTwo` so that there is a record for every `date` in labels array.  I am having a hard time coming up with an elegant solution for this. I keep ending up with double nested forEach paired with `.find()` Does anyone have a more concise method?

**EDIT**:

This is the best I've been able to come up with so far:

```
for ( let dataset in data ) {
  const nullFilled = labels.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
      const record = data[dataset].find(record => record.date === currentValue)
      return [...acc, record ? { ...record } : { date: currentValue, metric: null, value: null, dataset: null}]
    }, [])
  data[dataset] = nullFilled
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Please elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please be more clear, I think that you've tried something... Please share whatever you have done

Comment: As @hev1 stated,What is the end result ?

Answer (score 1):

i would first create object with value key from label. Then if date is within label add to the array. You can use set instead of object to transform label if you are using es6.

```js
let labels = [
  "2020-07-30",
  "2020-07-31",
  "2020-08-01",
  "2020-08-02",
  "2020-08-03",
  "2020-08-04",
  "2020-08-05",
  "2020-08-06"
]
labels = labels.reduce( 
( acc,cur)=> {  acc[cur] = cur; return acc; } 

,{})

console.log(labels)
const data = {
  "datasetOne": [
    {
      "date": "2020-07-30",
      "metric": "someMetric",
      "value": 5.6,
      "dataset": "datasetOne"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-07-31",
      "metric": "someMetric",
      "value": 5.9,
      "dataset": "datasetOne"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-08-01",
      "metric": "someMetric",
      "value": 5.7,
      "dataset": "datasetOne"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-08-02",
      "metric": "someMetric",
      "value": 7.7,
      "dataset": "datasetOne"
    }
  ],
  "datasetTwo": [
    {
      "date": "2020-08-02",
      "metric": "someOtherMetric",
      "value": 7.7,
      "dataset": "datasetTwo"
    }
  ]
};

let mergedData = [];

Object.entries(data).forEach(entry => {
  const [key, value] = entry;
  mergedData.push(value.reduce((acc,el)=>{
   if(labels[el.date.trim()]!=undefined ){
   
       acc.push(el)
   }
   
   return acc
  
  } ,[])
  )
});

console.log(mergedData)
```